# Show muliple records from mysql

Tags: php, database

I have a php webpage that I want it to show all forum threads at once. He is the current db code i have, it only shows on thread.

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die("could not connect to mysql"); 
mysql_select_db("") or die("could not connect to db");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reference")
or die(mysql_error());  


$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

echo "<strong>ref_thread_id:</strong> ".$row['ref_thread_id'].'<br />';
echo "<strong>ref_thread_prefix:</strong> ".$row['ref_thread_prefix'].'<br />';
echo "<strong>ref_thread_topic:</strong> ".$row['ref_thread_topic'].'<br />';
echo "<strong>ref_thread_content:</strong> ".$row['ref_thread_content'].'<br />';
```

How do I get it to spit out every record in this table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to use a while loop. the fetch functions only get one row at a time.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only grabbing the first record, loop through each one:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
  echo "<strong>ref_thread_id:</strong> ".$row['ref_thread_id'].'<br />';
  echo "<strong>ref_thread_prefix:</strong> ".$row['ref_thread_prefix'].'<br />';
  echo "<strong>ref_thread_topic:</strong> ".$row['ref_thread_topic'].'<br />';
  echo "<strong>ref_thread_content:</strong> ".$row['ref_thread_content'].'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}
```

(Example part taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)